# Not sure what element I need to click in IE HTML for VBA?

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

So I have the following HTML code (I'm not super familiar with HTML so excuse the incorrect spacing):

```
<div class="section_heading">

<span class="section_anchor" id="ajax_result_table_link" data-label="vs. Pitchers"></span>

<h2>vs. Pitchers</h2>    
<div class="section_heading_text">

<ul> 


<i>Sorting only sorts the values in the table shown</li>
    <li>Click a player to see each PA</li>

    <li class="hasmore drophover">
        <span href="javascript:void(0)">Share &amp; more</span>
    <div>
        <div class="closer" role="button" aria-label="close this menu"></div>
            <ul>
                <li><button class="tooltip" id="share_on_ajax_result_table" tip="Use a customizable report creator that can<br>output HTML, CSV, or a shareable link.">Modify &amp; Share Table</button>
                </li>
                <li><button class="tooltip" tip="Get a bit of widget code to emed this table on your site">Embed this Table</button></li>
                <li><button class="tooltip" tip="Convert the table below to comma-separated values<br>suitable for use with excel">Get as Excel Workbook (experimental)</button><a id="dlink" style="display: none;"></a></li>
                <li><button class="tooltip" tip="Export table as <br>suitable for use with excel">Get table as CSV (for Excel)</button></li><li><button class="tooltip" tip="">Strip Mobile Formatting</button></li>
```

From this URL: https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/batter_vs_pitcher.cgi?batter=mancitr01

I am trying to use VBA to download the Excel workbook (under the "Share & More" Dropdown), but I can't seem to be able to click the link. I've tried using get element by class and get element by ID but they don't seem to work. I'm guessing this HTML code is a little more advanced than I'm used to. I've been trying to click the ID "`dlink`" but I'm not sure if that is the end goal.

Any help or input would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/batter_vs_pitcher.cgi?batter=mancitr01"
    Wait 10
    IE.document.getElementById("dlink").Click


 Exit Sub

Set oElementCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("section_heading_text")
    For Each span In oElementCollection
    If span.innerHTML = "Share & more" Then
        span.ParentNode.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next span
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Which dropdown contains `Share & More` option and what have you tried so far with?

Comment: @SIM I really don't know how the "code" functionality works on this website. But I have added the VBA code. The first portion is the super basic example just attempting to use the ID. But the second part is trying to click the "Share and more" portion but did not have any luck with that. I tried various class names but none of them seemed to work. You can ignore the Exit Sub portions. I'm just testing out various things to see if they work, but have tested obviously excluding the Exit Sub portion.

Comment: Any error messages anywhere